# Not redirecting to home page in Django. While putting http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/connect/jhvjhb/3 in url

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

[Image Showing Error and Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zxbv.png)

When entering http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/connect/jhvjhb/3 in url as url is defined to take some random letters and at last primary key. It should redirect to home but its not working. I do not have idea about regular expressions.

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from home.views import HomeView
from . import views
app_name = 'home'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name="home"),
    path('connect/(?P<operation>.+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/', views.change_friends, name='change_friends')
]
```

moddels.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.


class Post(models.Model):
    post = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class Friend(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    current_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='owner', null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @classmethod
    def make_friend(cls, current_user, new_friend):
        friend, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(
            current_user=current_user    
        )
        friend.users.add(new_friend)

    @classmethod
    def lose_friend(cls, current_user, new_friend):
        friend, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(
            current_user=current_user    
        )
        friend.users.remove(new_friend)
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .forms import HomeForm
from .models import Post

class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home/home.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = HomeForm()
        posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-created')
        users = User.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id)

        args = {'form':form, 'posts':posts, 'users':users} 
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)

    def post(self, request):
        form = HomeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.user = request.user
            post.save()
            form = HomeForm()
            return redirect('home:home')

        args = {'form':form, 'text':text}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)


    def change_friends(request, operation, pk):
        return redirect('home:home')
```

Comment: If you want to use a regex in your url `path` then you should use `re_path`

Comment: re_path documentation here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#django.urls.re_path

Comment: @ChrisDoyle thank you it is working...